# TypeORM does not create tables, columns etc

Tags: typeorm

I have set up a system with typeorm (https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm) and NestJs (https://github.com/nestjs/nest), but TypeORM isn't creating the tables or columns. My setup is like this:

```js
import {UserPassword} from '../user/user-password.entity';
import {User} from '../user/user.entity';

createConnection({
    type: 'mysql',
    host: 'typeorm2.cn32tstd6wqk.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    port: 1234,
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'dbname',
    entities: [
      // __dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'
      UserPassword,
      User
    ]
  })
```

And the entities are:

```ts
import {Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, OneToOne, JoinColumn} from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class UserPassword {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  hash: string;

  @Column()
  algorithm: string;

}
```

and

```ts
import {Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, OneToOne, JoinColumn} from 'typeorm';
import {UserPassword} from './user-password.entity';

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ length: 35 })
  firstName: string;

  @Column({ length: 35 })
  lastName: string;

  @Column({ length: 50})
  mail: string;

  @OneToOne(type => UserPassword)
  @JoinColumn()
  password: UserPassword;

}
```

Then I try to create a user like this:

```ts
// ... some code
await this.userPasswordRepository.save(userPassword);
return await this.userRepository.save(user);
```

But I get the following error:

> QueryFailedError: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'typeorm2.user_password' doesn't exist

When I insert the table manually then I get the error:

> QueryFailedError: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'hash' in 'field list'

So it seems like TypeORM doesn't generate the tables / columns. Does anyone know why this could be?

Comment: hi, i also meet this problem and have you fix it well ?

Answer (score 46):

Even though the previous answers are acceptable for **development** environment, they are **wrong for production**.

What you are looking for are migrations. Migrations are executed when connection is established and are recorded - no migration will run more than once. TypeORM also provides CLI which allows you to generate migrations ([read more here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/using-cli.md#create-a-new-migration)), making it much faster to create them. TypeORM also marks each migration with a timestamp prefix, ensuring they will run in proper sequence - sometimes you might want to run migrations in primary tables first, sometimes on supporting tables. When configuring connection, you load migrations like this:

```js
createConnection({
    type: 'mysql',
    host: 'typeorm2.cn32tstd6wqk.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    port: 1234,
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'dbname',
    entities: [
        // __dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'
        UserPassword,
        User
    ],
    migrations: ['./migrations/*.js'],
    synchronize: false
})
```

Migrations are built composed of 2 parts - **up** (migration code) and **down** (code to revert migration). Simple example:

```js
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from 'typeorm';

export class AddImageToUser implements MigrationInterface {

    async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
        await queryRunner.query(
                'ALTER TABLE "user" ADD image varchar(255)'
        );
    }
    async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
        await queryRunner.query(
                'ALTER TABLE "user" DROP COLUMN image'
        );
    }
}
```

If you want to read more, TypeORM has detailed description on their official Git repository [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/migrations.md#creating-a-new-migration)

In general, it is not good to leave the synchronization of the data and schema to the framework. It is something that should be done by you to ensure the database schema will be preserved. The CLI I linked before also allows you to run migrations and therefore test them before pushing changes to production.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead); instead, provide answers according to [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thanks @Anna, I updated my answer to provide sufficient information.

Comment: The question is about entities not syncing tables which they should with `synchronize: true`. But this answer is about db migration.

Comment: You absolutely should not use `synchronize: true` in production cases. The answer does answer the question as OP's issue is about synchronization and the tables not getting created.

Comment: @JiriKralovec why should you not use `synchronize: true`  in prod? I'm not challenging that statement, I'm just not sure as I was intending to use it.

Comment: @K-Dawg The issue with using `synchronize: true` is the unpredictability. It is safer (and much more maintainable) to simply write a migration with explicit `up/down` function, which will make it much easier to track changes and potentially do a rollback safely.

Answer (score 26):

Connection has ‘synchronize()’ method. You can use it to create tables and columns automatically:

```
const connection = await createConnection(...);
await connection.synchronize();
```

Comment: Hi, is it possible to create new table and run migration automatically after application is running in production mode? My question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56617592/typeorm-how-to-create-new-table-and-run-migration-automatically-in-production

Comment: @JerryChong I guess yes. It works for my cases :) You can try it on develop. There are only 2 rows.

Answer (score 9):

Manually specifying entities instead of the wildcard path name worked for me.

```
export let dbOptions: ConnectionOptions = {
     type: "mysql",
     host: "localhost",
     port: 3306,
     username: "root",
     password: "root",
     database: "exam",
     synchronize: true,

     entities: [
          // "./entities/*.js",     // Wildcard Path : Not working
          EmployeeEntity            // Specify the entities directly.
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

By adding the following to `ormconfig.json/js/xml/etc`:

```
synchronize: true
```

It creates the table once if it does not exists.

Comment: It must be noted that setting this is not good for production. It will alter the table and cause data loss.

Answer (score 5):

In your ormconfig.json file set "synchronize"--> true (boolean)

This should work

```html
{
    "type": "mysql",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5432,
    "username": "root",
    "password": "root",
    "database": "Identity_Demo",
    "synchronize": true,
    "logging": true,
    "entities": ["dist/**/*.entity.js"]
 }
```

Comment: `synchronize: true` should not be used in production. Doing so will cause you to lose your production data. [The docs](https://typeorm.io/data-source-options#:~:text=Be%20careful%20with%20this%20option%20and%20don%27t%20use%20this%20in%20production%20%2D%20otherwise%20you%20can%20lose%20production%20data) even explicitly mention this!

Answer (score 4):

What helped me was adding the name of the model to the "Entity()" decorator:

```
@Entity({ name: 'User' })
```

Answer (score 3):

I switched to typeorm version **0.1.0-alpha.40** that has the option `autoSchemaSync` when creating a connection, which made it work:

```
createConnection({
  type: 'mysql',
  host: 'typeorm2.cn32tstd6wqk.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
  port: 1234,
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'dbname',
  entities: [
    // __dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'
    UserPassword,
    User
  ],
  autoSchemaSync: true,
})
```

Comment: This option was present from the first version of typeorm. Btw, you are using old version of TypeORM. Current version is 0.1.1 and `autoSchemaSync: true` now is just `synchronize: true`

Answer (score 3):

For your specific use case, adding `synchronize: true` might solve the issue but for the ones facing a similar issue, there might be some other reasons despite `synchronize: true`. Some of them are:

1. Decorate your entity with `@Entity()` so that `typeORM` can recognize it and generate the table(only if `synchronize` is `true`).
2. Include the entity in the respective module's imports as:

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([<Your_Entity>])],
  .......
})
```

With these in place, tables will be automatically created. However, is it safe to use `synchronize: true`? might be another topic as answered by @Jiri Kralovec.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Jose Miguel's answer

If you used `typeorm-model-generator` to generate your entities for the first time from the DB to the code then maybe `typeorm-model-generator` might have generated your code with something like this.

```
@Entity('yourTableName', { schema: 'public' })
```

I removed `{ schema: 'public' }` leaving it like

```
@Entity('yourTableName')
```

this fixed the issue for me.
Hope it helps someone in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that the Entity I wanted to generate migration for was not an exported class.

Answer (score 0):

I had a stupid issue.

All the configuration was correct, just my entity file was not saved after all the changes.

Should definitely turn on auto save.

Comment: Haha, it actually happens sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Use TypeORM CLI to manually create tables based on the entities in the datasource file **data-source.ts**:

```
typeorm-ts-node-commonjs schema:sync --dataSource data-source.ts
```

If the datasource file is in JavaScript, then the following command can be used instead:

```
typeorm schema:sync --dataSource data-source.js
```