# TypeORM - How to create new table and run migration automatically in production mode?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, typeorm

I would like to create new table in MySQL and run TypeORM migration automatically when application running in production mode.

**Note: This new table is not created prior starting of application in production mode.**

According to [Migration Documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/migrations.md), it need to use **typeorm migration:run** command to run migration.

Due to my new table only created when application called **CreateNewTableTimeStamp(inputTableName).up**, at this point it will trigger to create new table into my database.

But I found no solution how to do this migration automatically, since it is impossible for me to run **typeorm migration:run** manually each time application called this method to create new table.

After this table is created, I will write new data into this new table afterwards.

Could anyone assist on this issue?

Thanks.

**My New Table Code:**

```
class CreateNewTableTimeStamp implements MigrationInterface  {

  tableName: string;

  constructor (inputTableName: string) {
    this.tableName = inputTableName
  }

  async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
    await queryRunner.createTable(new Table({
          name: this.tableName,
          columns: [
              {
                  name: "id",
                  type: "int",
                  isPrimary: true
              },
              {
                  name: "email",
                  type: "varchar",
              }
          ]
      }), true)
  }

  async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
    const table = await queryRunner.getTable(this.tableName);
    await queryRunner.dropTable(this.tableName);
  }
}
```

Comment: I would not recommand running migrations from your server code, it should be done before launching your node server with a CLI command. It is best to not bring a hard dependency between code and SQL migration structure as code would evolve, and the migration should always be immutable and replayed. I would encourage you to generate raw SQL queries so no "code" is executed (imagine TypeOrm changes its way to execute queryRunner, your migration could become mutable depending on the version of TypeOrm!).

Comment: @zenbeni, thanks for your advice. Will change my design not to do migrations from my server code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @zenbeni in the comment, it is not recommended to running migrations from your server code, as the migration should always be immutable and replayed.

Therefore, I would change my design not to do migrations from my server code.

Answer (score 2):

For people wanting to run migrations for the **purpose of Testing and
NOT in production environment**.

```
import {
  createConnection,
  ConnectionOptions,
  Connection,
} from 'typeorm';

import { YourEntity } from 'path/to/your/entity.ts';

const testConfig: ConnectionOptions = {
  type: 'mongodb',
  url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017',
  database: 'test',
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  entities: [YourEntity],
  synchronize: true,
  migrations: ['migrations/*YourMigrations.ts'],
};

let connection: Connection;

connection = await createConnection({ ...testConfig });
await connection.synchronize(true);

await connection.runMigrations({
 transaction: 'all',
});
```

Run using:

```
node -r ts-node/register ./path/to/migrations.ts
```

or

```
node ./path/to/compiled/migrations.js
```

Comment: This workaround looks nice but can you explain why is not a good practice synchronize the database on production runtime?

Comment: The issue is not about synchronising the data in production. It's more about how do you want to do it production. 

This script is about updating the migrations manually - meaning by calling a script from terminal to update the db. 

I believe this must be done using: 
-  the automatic way of running migrations that stores the migration info in db. 

- must be in consultation by how your devops team wants to handle the changes to DB. Many times the app is not allowed to drop or create collections/indexes.

Answer (score -2):

Run

`yarn typeorm migration:create -n users`(table_name)

**Table code example:**

```
   import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner, Table } from 'typeorm';

export class createUsers1585025619325 implements MigrationInterface {
  private table = new Table({
    name: 'users',
    columns: [
      {
        name: 'id',
        type: 'integer',
        isPrimary: true,
        isGenerated: true, // Auto-increment
        generationStrategy: 'increment',
      },
      {
        name: 'email',
        type: 'varchar',
        length: '255',
        isUnique: true,
        isNullable: false,
      },
      {
        name: 'created_at',
        type: 'timestamptz',
        isNullable: false,
        default: 'now()',
      },
      {
        name: 'updated_at',
        type: 'timestamptz',
        isNullable: false,
        default: 'now()',
      },
    ],
  });

  public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
    await queryRunner.createTable(this.table);
  }
  public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
    await queryRunner.dropTable(this.table);
  }
}
```

Run created migrations with:

```
yarn typeorm migration:run
```

Comment: this is not automatically generation method