# How to create new tables at runtime with nestjs and typeorm in http call with tablename as parameter

Tags: database, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I need to dynamically create new tables in my mysql-database whenever the route /roles/create is being called. The body paramerer "name" of the http-call should be the name of the new table. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56617592/typeorm-how-to-create-new-table-and-run-migration-automatically-in-production) so articel creating tables at runtime is not recommended. How else would you do something like this? Doesnt there have to be a way to do this on runtime? How else do companies accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you need new tables? Why not new rows in the table instead?

Comment: Every role should have multiple users. To keep the database clean every role should have its own table of users, that makes deleting roles much simpler than if all users are stored in one table. Instead of going through all users and deleting the ones with the correct role, I can just delete the whole role table.

Comment: That sounds like a many to many relationship with extra steps. You should not be dynamically creating tables. Tables should be purposefully created and maintained with relations, in my opinion

Comment: Exactly, having predefined tables will force you to think ahead about how you will implement your domain logic and at the same time enforce the data integrity paradigm