# TypeORM not create table on startup

Tags: javascript, typescript, sqlite, typeorm

I want ot run migration on application startup with using typeorm and sqlite db. Below is my current configuration:

```
      return {
        type: "sqlite",
        database: "sqlite_db",
        synchronize: true,
        entities: [
          Account
        ],
        migrations: [MigrationOnStartup],
        migrationsTransactionMode: "each",
        migrationsRun: true,
        logging: false,
        autoLoadEntities: true
      }
```

and here is my simple migration to create new account in db if not exists:

```
    async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
        const connection = queryRunner.connection;

        const account = await connection.getRepository(Account).findOneBy({ email: "admin@admin" });
        if (!account) {
            await connection.getRepository(Account).insert({
                email: "admin@admin",
                name: "admin",
                username: "admin"
            });
        }
    }
```

Can someone tell me why on app startup, typeorm not create `Account` table and threw me this error:

```
QueryFailedError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: account
```

I have no idea what can i do more than this what is in configuration.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you post the Account class with decorations ?
One more note: ```synchronize: true``` is not recommended for production use cases. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46843385/typeorm-does-not-create-tables-columns-etc

Comment: @SvetoslavPetkov Account class has only Entity decorator above the class